# How to pass a variable to a regular expression (re.findall)

Tags: python, regex, linux

```
date= 2021-02-10

result = re.findall(r'\s{2}'+date+r'\d{4}.*Pattern)
print("Result is ", result)
```

I am trying to retrieve results of a particular date via re.findall(). I am not sure about passing a variable inside re.findall().
Currently, this is returning a null value Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

`findall` accepts a string.  It doesn't know whether the string was a constant or constructed from parts.  As long as your result is a valid regular expression, it will work.

```
date = '2021-02-10'
result = = re.findall( r'\s{8}'+date+r'\d{4}', haystack )
```

But why would the date be followed by 4 digits?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: There is some other digits after the date in my content to test

Comment: How did you generate the date string?

Comment: I made this work, In Python, we need to use \\double slash instead of single slash. Thanks, everyone for helping me out with this.

Working code:
re.findall(r'\s{8}'+date+':\\d{4}.*Pattern', haystack)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine f-strings and r-strings into rf-strings that way you can pass variables (which are strings as well or have a valid string representation you want) into string patterns. For your example you can do this:

```
date= rf"2021-02-10"
data_string = "some string where you want to find matches in."
result = re.findall(rf'\s{{8}}{date}\d{{4}}.*', data_string)
print("Result is ", result)
```

Also, like @Tim Roberts mentioned, your usage of re.findall() is not correct. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: I was going to suggest the `rf` strings, but there's a problem:  `f"{8}"` produces `8` -- it consumes the braces!

Comment: If you don't want braces to be consumed inside f-strings you can use it like this, f"{{8}}"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out forgot to modify the pattern properly. I have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
date= 2021-02-10

result = re.findall(r'\s{8}'+date+':\\d{4}.*Pattern', haystack)
print("Result is ", result)
```

This works. In python, we use double slash instead of single slash as it is an invalid escape sequence.
Thanks, everyone for helping me out with this.